# AWS sts error: The security token included in the request is expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Why when I run the command...

```
aws --profile default sts get-caller-identity
```

it works and I get the expected result back. But when I attempt to run...

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

It fails with the error "*An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is expired*"

I've configured aws sso correctly and have successfully given my machine permission. I've ensure that there are no AWS environment variables set in my user or system environment variables (no environment variable prefixed with 'AWS_')

Comment: Use the `--debug` option with awscli to see what's going on. Compare the credentials loaded in the two invocations. They'll be labelled `botocore.credentials`. Tragically awscli [emits logs to stderr](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5187) so you can grep as follows: `aws sts get-caller-identity --debug 2>&1 | grep botocore.credentials`.

Comment: Oh it seems to suggest there's credentials somewhere in my environment variables
2024-03-28 13:00:11,472 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2024-03-28 13:00:11,472 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in environment variables.

Comment: Thanks jarmod managed to solve the issue with your helpful debugging tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so thanks to @jarmod's comment on my question I was able to isolate the issue, by using the logs produced from the command:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --debug 2>&1 | Select-String "botocore.credentials"
```

which outputted:

```
2024-03-28 13:00:11,472 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2024-03-28 13:00:11,472 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in environment variables.
```

So I ran the commands:

```
Remove-Item -Path Env:\AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
Remove-Item -Path Env:\AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

and reran the above command which gave me the output of:

```
2024-03-28 13:04:14,393 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2024-03-28 13:04:14,393 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2024-03-28 13:04:14,393 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2024-03-28 13:04:14,393 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: sso
2024-03-28 13:04:14,541 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Credentials for role retrieved from cache.
2024-03-28 13:04:14,541 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Retrieved credentials will expire at: 2024-03-28 20:56:29+00:00
```

Now when I run the command:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

it works as expected.